# Ruby - how do I run a method on each array element on different threads?

Tags: ruby, arrays, multithreading

So I have an array of 40000 elements, and I wish to run a method on each element.

To reduce the time it will take, I am thinking of running this on multiple threads. Perhaps splitting the array into multiple arrays and running on a different thread or something. But I don't know how to get started.

Say the array is foo[], and the method to call is bar(). bar() returns a string. After the code executes, I want to be able to combine/add up all the strings together in one big string.

Is there a way to do this? I tried to keep my question as simple as possible, but if you want more information, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want something like a pmap function. There is a ruby library called [peach](http://peach.rubyforge.org/) that provides both a pmap and a peach ("parallel" each) method on the native arrays.

With this library, you can do something like

```
require 'peach'
[1,2,3,4].pmap{|x| f(x)} #Spawns 4 threads, => [f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4)]
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `a.pmap(n) { ... }` can be used to limit yourself to only `n` threads, Gbert90's computer would probably get upset with him if he tried to launch 40k threads.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work for a large array. Is there any article/book that can help with this?

Comment: How big your array? Did you try limiting the number of threads as suggested in the above comment with `a.pmap(n) {...}`? Just make sure than n <= # of cpu's in your system.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to achieve concurrency, and using threads is one way. However, the best performance depends on the Ruby runtime you choose.

For example, one simple way to multithread is the 'peach' (parallel each) library http://peach.rubyforge.org/. However, this works best on JRuby, which uses native threads.

For the MRI runtime you may want to use multiple processes like [DRb](http://segment7.net/projects/ruby/drb/introduction.html) or a message bus like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

For a great writeup on the many options, see this post: http://merbist.com/2011/02/22/concurrency-in-ruby-explained/

Answer (score 2):

If I properly understand, you need something like this snippet:

```
foo = %w{1 2 3}  # => ["1", "2", "3"]

# in your case it would be some time-consumed operation on string
def inc(element)
  element.succ
end  # => nil 
inc("1")  # => "2" 

threads = foo.map do |f|
  Thread.new { inc(f) }
end
# => [#<Thread:0x8d28694 run>, #<Thread:0x8d28630 run>, #<Thread:0x8d28590 run>] 

threads.map { |t| t.value }  # => ["2", "3", "4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Eventmachine, which allows you to run 'pseudo-parallel' on a single thread.  See [EM::Iterator](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/em/iterator.rb) - for example:

```
ret = nil

EM.run do

  # run 10 at a time; you can set the concurrency level to whatever you want
  # but processing will slow down depending on how costly your bar method is

  EM::Iterator.new(foo, 10).map( 
    proc{|item, iter| iter.return(item.bar)}, 
    proc{|results| ret = results.join; EM.stop}
  )

end
```